# SAPUI5 Custom Fields in SmartTable destroy SmartTable functionality

Tags: sapui5

I have a Smarttable where I have added a few custom fields. Before I have added the custom fields, Smarttable features, e.g. row selection check box, horizontal scroll bar or a summation line (table type is analytical table), have been working, but now with the custom fields, these features are not working anymore. As you can see in my code, I have added no mode = MultiSelect and fixedLayout=false, but my question is, am I doing something wrong how I added the custom field or is it normal, that the smarttable features are destroyed, when adding my own fields?

```
<smartTable:SmartTable>
 <Table id="customTable" mode="MultiSelect" fixedLayout="false">
                <columns>
                    <Column id="TotalStock">
                        <customData>
                        <core:CustomData key="p13nData" value='\{"columnKey": "Total_Stock", "leadingProperty": "Total_Stock", "columnIndex": "7"}'/>
                        </customData>
                        <Text text="{i18n>Total_Stock}"></Text>
                    </Column>
               </columns>
  </Table>
</smartTable:SmartTable>
```